# Stacking up dataframes in a 3-dimenional numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have several pandas dataframe that I would like to stack them up using numpy as a three-dimensional numpy array. I could manually do the job using the following code:

```
arr = np.array([df1.values, df2.values], dtype="object")
```

However, since I have many dataframes, I can neither write this line for all the dataframes nor automate it.

I tried to use `append` function (`np.append(df1.values, df2['1002'].values)`) but it flattens dataframes and ignores their structure. What I want is a three-dimensional numpy array where the first dimension is the number of dataframes (that I have), the second one is the number of rows in each dataframe, and the third one is the number of columns. In the first example that I mentioned earlier, I get a three-dimensional numpy array. In fact when I run `arr.shape` the result is `(2,)` and when I run `arr[0].shape` and `arr[1].shape`, I get `(26, 7)` and `(24, 7)`, respectively which are the structure of their corresponding dataframe.

I even ran `np.append(df1.values, df2['1002'].values, axis=0)` but I received the error of `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly`. Is there any way that I can fix this problem and stack up all my dataframes in a 3-dimensional numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you start with 2 frames with 7 columns, but different numbers of rows.  The equivalent of:

```
In [1]: arr1 = np.ones((26,7)); arr2 = np.zeros((24,7))
   ...: 
In [2]: arr = np.array([arr1, arr2], object)
In [3]: arr.shape
Out[3]: (2,)
In [4]: arr[0].shape
Out[4]: (26, 7)
```

You probably tried this without the `object` and got a 'ragged array' warning.  In any case, this is **not** a 3d array.  It is 1d `(2,)`, with two arrays.  It's roughly the same as the list

```
[arr1, arr2]
```

The `np.append` docs should make it clear that it flattens the arguments, when you don't specify an axis.

```
In [6]: np.append(arr1,arr2).shape
Out[6]: (350,)
```

You could specify an axis, and get a 2d array, where the 50 is the sum of 26 and 24.

```
In [7]: np.append(arr1,arr2,axis=0).shape
Out[7]: (50, 7)
```

This is the same as:

```
In [8]: np.concatenate((arr1,arr2), axis=0).shape
Out[8]: (50, 7)
```

`np.append` is poorly name cover for `np.concatenate`.  It is not a list append clone.  Learn to use `concatenate` and its `stack` derivatives.  In

With different dataframe shapes, you cannot make a 3d array.  Arrays cannot be 'ragged'.

As for working with more than 2 dataframes, if you can make a list of all the frames, you can use the initial syntax.

```
alist = []
for a in frame_list:
    alist.append(a.values)
arr = np.array(alist, object)
```

But make such array doesn't do much for you.

If the frames are all the same size, then you can make a 3d array

```
In [10]: np.array([arr1[:10,:],arr2[:10,:]]).shape
Out[10]: (2, 10, 7)
In [11]: np.stack([arr1[:10,:],arr2[:10,:]]).shape
Out[11]: (2, 10, 7)
```

But if they differ, `stack` will complain about that:

```
In [12]: np.stack([arr1, arr2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-12-23d05d0422dc>", line 1, in <module>
    np.stack([arr1, arr2])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in stack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 426, in stack
    raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```